# LaTeX doesn't like my equation... what's up?

Tags: equations, amsmath

It's been awhile since I've used LaTeX to write. I'm trying to write a simple equation into my text, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I'm sure it's quite simple, but even after comparing with other similar texts, I cannot identify what's wrong with the equation, nor whether or not I'm missing something in the preamble.

Please check it out. My LaTeX program keeps giving me a ton of error messages such as missing $, extra }, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx,dcolumn,ragged2e,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
y_{ijt} = \alpha_{0} + \textbf{x_{ijt} \varphi} + c_{i} + s_{j} + \tau_{t} + \varepsilon_{ijt}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you write ` \textbf{` before `x_{ijt}`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Probably to get a bold math font...

Comment: @TeXnician Probable, I saw your answer, but it seems a bit strange to have one variabile bold if the other ones in the equation are not... but I'm not a mathematician :):):)

Answer (score 4):

You should change `\textbf{x_{ijt}}` to `\mathbf{x}_{ijt}` and exclude the phi from the bold part.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx,dcolumn,ragged2e,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
y_{ijt} = \alpha_{0} + \mathbf{x}_{ijt} \varphi + c_{i} + s_{j} + \tau_{t} + \varepsilon_{ijt}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that both `x` in `x_{ijt}` and `\varphi` should be typeset in bold -- but not the `ijt` index. Moreover, the product of these two variables should be an inner product, right? If so, load the `bm` ("bold math") package and write

```
{\bm{x}_{ijt}}'\bm{\varphi}
```

A full MWE (with a much-simplified preamble):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\[
y_{ijt} = \alpha_{0} + {\bm{x}_{ijt}}'\bm{\varphi} + c_{i} + s_{j} 
          + \tau_{t} + \varepsilon_{ijt}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer `\bm{x}'_{ijt}}` ;-)

Comment: @Tarass - Thanks. I guess I'm trying to indicate -- possibly too pedantically -- that `'` is being used as the transpose-cum-multiplication operator, between the vectors `\bm{x}_{ijt}` and `\bm{\varphi}`. I'll freely admit to the possibility of having misinterpreted the OP's reasons for bold-facing some of the symbols.

Comment: I can't guess what OP wants. But the ' seems to far from x. That's all. Thank you.